# Whether to wait for my phone model Ubuntu Touch and developed it at all?

Tags: ubuntu-touch

I'm from Russia, and I write through a translator. I would like to know whether the available OS Ubuntu Touch on XPERIA phones in 2012, ie XPERIA Ion? I really like this system, and wanted to try it on my phone. I'd buy the Nexus, but I do it for personal reasons, do not like.

Thank you.

Daniil Makarov, Russia

Answer (score 1):

A guide has been posted to [port it](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Porting).

So if your phone support minimum configuration & CM10 build available for it, then you can port it. Now most of the Xperia devices have problem with the amount of internal memory. If your devices has at least 4GB internal memory (**not only intenal memory, you need to specifically check the amount of `/system` patition**) you can proceed. Also check, related XDA forum to know about developments (if any)

various Devs are working on porting, you can check the list from here https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Devices

Currently, only Xperia S & T are listed.